# Excel: CountIf RangeA is n units larger than Range B

Tags: excel, countif, sumproduct

I want to count the number of times values in RangeA exceed the values in RangeB by n units; only comparing values in the same row.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RangeA < RangeB))
```

works as a start, but I want to be able to change the tolerance
ie.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(RangeA < (RangeB + n))
```

Comment: And that does not work?  It should:  `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4<B1:B4-2))` will count how many times A is less than B - 2

Comment: Nope. I have tried: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(RangeA<RangeB-n))` and `=SUMPRODUCT(--(RangeA<(RangeB-n))`in hopes that it was a mere parenthesis error, but both return a `#VALUE!` error.

Comment: Then most likely the fault is in the data.  Please post a sample of the data.

Comment: Got it. I was using a full column range `A:A`, but it will only work with row indexes `A2:A999`. If there a way to do this with full column ranges? I would like to use my named ranges.

Comment: With SUMPRODUCT the data must all be numbers.  The issue is the title row.

Comment: I have text titles in Row1, so that's the issue. Since my row count changes over time, I'll have to settle for `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A99999<(B2:B99999+n)))-99999+COUNTA(A:A)`

Comment: See my edit to the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula works for me:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A4<B1:B4+2))
```

[image]

It appears that the issues is the title row.  Start at Row 2 and use a dynamic end:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($A$2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))<$B$2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,B:B))+2))
```

This will now start at row 2 and make a dynamic range of only the data.

[image]

Comment: Do you have you give row references, or can you use `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A<B:B+2))`  ?

Comment: Great. I never knew you could give a formula a dynamic end. Cool tip.